# Ubuntu 14.04 Python Numpy version change

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, scipy

A numpy version 1.8.2 is installed on my Ubuntu, however I did install version 1.11.0 using pip install.

When I do: pip show numpy this is the result

- Name: numpy
- Version: 1.11.0
- Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
- Requires:

however when run python and I do

```
np.__version__
```

It give: 1.8.2.

I tried to solve but I couldnt, can someone help me with this perhaps simple issue. Thanks

Comment: Run `which -a python` Also did you use apt-get or pip to install originally?

Comment: when i run which -a python I get /usr/bin/python. I used pip to install

Comment: So you never `apt-get install python-numpy`? from a python shell, import numpy and run `numpy.__file__`

Comment: Actually I use ROS, so that is installed as ROS deps. Besides the result of numpy.__file__: is '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'

Comment: Well there is your problem, your pip installs to  `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and you have another version in `/usr/lib...`, run  `import site; site.getsitepackages()`

Comment: The output is: ['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']

Comment: Just verify cd to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and import numpy, also run  `import sys;sys.path`  based on `getsitepackages` it seems you should get `/usr/local/lib` first but just verify it is first in the path

Comment: When I cd to dist-packages directory and import I get version 1.9.1

Comment: The fact 1.9.1 shows means there is something radically wrong with your setup, how many different ways have you installed numpy?

Comment: numpy 1.8.2 was installed when I installed ros. Other than that I did pip install numpy=1.9.1 and I once I did easy_install numpy.

Comment: Considering you are messing with the system python I would strongly suggest to use pyenv or a virtualenv but if you want to sort the issue out, first completely remove all traces of numpy from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Comment: so I remove all the numpy files, then install again using virtualenv?

Comment: You can reinstall with pip after removing if you want and you should have access to 1.11.0  but I would suggest you use pyenv/virtualenv to isolate the environment. I suggested removing all traces as from installing multiple ways has screwed something up. Removing will have no affect on your system

Comment: Thank you very much  I am going to do that.